# SQL how to simulate an xor?

Tags: sql

I'm wondering if anybody can help me solve this question I got at a job interview. Let's say I have two tables like:

```
table1                 table2
------------           -------------
id | name              id | name
------------           -------------
 1 | alpha              1 | alpha
 3 | charlie            3 | charlie
 4 | delta              5 | echo
 8 | hotel              7 | golf
 9 | india
```

The question was to write a SQL query that would return all the rows that are in either `table1` or `table2` but not both, i.e.:

```
result
------------
id | name
------------
 4 | delta
 5 | echo
 7 | golf
 8 | hotel
 9 | india
```

I thought I could do something like a full outer join:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* 
FROM table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id=table2.id 
WHERE table1.id IS NULL or table2.id IS NULL
```

but that gives me a syntax error on SQL Fiddle (I don't think it supports the `FULL OUTER JOIN` syntax). Other than that, I can't even figure out a way to just concatenate the rows of the two tables, let alone filtering out rows that appear in both. Can somebody enlighten me and tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have that fiddle? If so, could you post it?

Comment: @jay . . . SQL Fiddle supports several SQL engines.  The only one that doesn't support `full outer join` is MySQL, which happens to be the default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select id,name--,COUNT(*)
from(
select id,name from table1 
union all 
select id,name from table2
) x
group by id,name
having COUNT(*)=1
```

Comment: @OmarTariq it would but you would need to use a min or max operation in the exterior select to get the name.

Comment: upon reading the question I initially just thought select -> t1 union t2 except (t1 union t2)  but my assumption is that this answer is more performant without doing any tests.

Comment: fyi:  I found my way here looking for an xor operation with the same syntax as union or intersect...  ie
    select * from t1
    xor
    select * from t2

Answer (score 16):

Well, you could use `UNION` instead of `OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Here's a little trick I know: *not equals* is the same as XOR, so you could have your `WHERE` clause something like this:

```
WHERE ( table1.id IS NULL ) != ( table2.id IS NULL )
```

Comment: For `not equal to` operator you mean `<>`?

Comment: Yes. In fact, both symbols work :) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there are lots of solutions, but the first thing that comes to mind for me is to `union all` the two tables, then group by name, filter with a `having` clause on the count.

Answer (score 4):

```
(
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
)
```

Comment: In Postgres (and Oracle) you'll need to put the two `except` queries into paranthises, otherwise the result is not correct: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1851e/2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, I am not that familiar with Postgres. I did some research before posting, and saw EXCEPT was a valid command. I didn't know the syntax was different. Corrected my answer to match your link

Comment: FWIW, SQLite doesn't need the parens

Answer (score 0):

This should work on most database servers

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM table1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND table1.name = table2.name)
 UNION ALL
SELECT id, name 
  FROM table2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND table1.name = table2.name)
```