# Find unmatching records from two tables having null values

Tags: oracle

I want to find unmatching val records from table2. It's having null values also

table1

```
id  val
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   null
```

table2

```
id  val
1   10
3   30
4   null
```

for above example its should return 20.

Comment: What if table2 contains a line with `val=40`? Should that line also be returned? If so, have a look at this question: [SQL how to simulate an xor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135734/sql-how-to-simulate-an-xor)

Answer (score 0):

Simple exists structure works here

```
with tmp1 as(
  select 1 id, 10 val from dual
  union
  select 2 id, 20 val from dual
  union
  select 3 id, 30 val from dual
  union
  select 4 id, null val from dual),
tmp2 as(
  select 1 id, 10 val from dual
  union
  select 3 id, 30 val from dual
  union
  select 4 id, null val from dual)

select
  tmp1.*
from
  tmp1
where
  not exists(
    select
      null
    from
      tmp2
    where
      nvl(tmp1.val,-1) = nvl(tmp2.val,-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MINUS` operator

```
select id, val from table1
minus
select id, val from table2
```

It selects all rows from the upper query which are not in the lower query

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02791/2)

Comment: or if he just cares about unmatched "val" values:  select val from table1 MINUS select val from table2;